# Implementing angularJs factory or service for bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs

how to write a service or factory for bootstrap tabs using angularJs.
I placed in one controller but need a common function(repeated code) for different controllers.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li data-ng-class="{active:tab===0}">
        <a href ng-click="changeTab(0)"> <i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{active:tab===1}">
        <a href ng-click="changeTab(1)"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div data-ng-class="{activeTab:tab===0}" ng-show="isActiveTab(0)">
  tab1
</div>
<div data-ng-class="{activeTab:tab===1}" ng-show="isActiveTab(1)">
  tab2
</div>
```

### **controller**

```
$scope.tab = 0;    
    $scope.changeTab = function(newTab){
      $scope.tab = newTab;
    };    
    $scope.isActiveTab = function(tab){
      return $scope.tab === tab;
    };
```

Comment: You may want to look at [AngularJS Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I recommend using directives and have your "tab" directives register and talk to its parent "tabContainer" directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I write it with out using any service or factory 
see the example

```
<ul ng-init="tab = 1">          
    <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"> 
      <a href ng-click="tab = 1">Tab1</a>               
    </li>           
    <li ng-class="{active:tab===2}"> 
       <a href ng-click="tab = 2">Tab2</a>              
    </li>           
    <li ng-class="{active:tab===3}"> 
      <a href ng-click="tab = 3">Tab3</a>           
    </li>           
    <br><br> 
    <p ng-show="tab === 1"> Tab1 content </p>           
    <p ng-show="tab === 2"> Tab2 content</p> 
    <p ng-show="tab === 3"> Tab3 content</p>        
</ul>
```

Dynamically change it through controller see the working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O7Mzts?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Vamsi..But i need to active tab1 dynamically(my requirement) using controller.

Comment: @vishnu good, But initially  I am using  ng-init for choosing tab1 try it change through controller i hope it's use full.

Comment: could u please give me a code how do i change, i tried $scope.tab=1. but not working.

Answer (score 4):

Managing tabs is a view concern. Rather than implementing a factory, I recommend creating two directives: `tabContainer` and `tab`.  The `tab` directive registers itself with the parent `tabContainer` using the `require` attribute to access the parent directive's controller API.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DX5yz8X4FHMmnQvDZNDG?p=preview)

#### Usage

```
<tab-container selected="tab2">
   <tab name="tab1">tab1</tab>
   <tab name="tab2">tab2</tab>
</tab-container>
```

### Parent Directive

The parent directive publishes the following controller API that the child tab directives will access:

**tabContainer controller**

```
// registers this tab with the parent tabContainer
this.register = function(element) {
  $scope.tabs.push(element);
}
// returns the selected tab object whose 
// name property indicates which tab is active
this.getSelected = function() {
  return $scope.selectedTab;
}
```

### Child Directive

The tab directive is able to access the parent controller by requiring the parent directive in its directive definition, and accessing the parent directive's controller as the 4th argument to the tab directive's link function:

**tab directive definition**

```
scope: true,
require: '^tabContainer',
link: function(scope, element, attr, tabContainer) {
  // set the tab so that it is visible in the tab directive's scope.
  scope.tab = { name: attr.name, element:element};
  scope.selectedTab = tabContainer.getSelected();
  tabContainer.register(scope.tab);

}
```

The scope is set to `true` so that each tab will create its own child scope and not interfere with the scope of other tabs.

### Template Files

For example purposes, the directive templates are embedded in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tabContainer.html">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-ng-class="{active:selectedTab.name===tab.name}">
      <a href ng-click="changeTab(tab)"> <i class="fa fa-list">{{tab.name}}</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tab.html">
 <div data-ng-class="{activeTab:selectedTab.name===tab.name}" ng-show="selectedTab.name === tab.name">
     <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
 </div>
</script>
```

It is recommended to move these to dedicated HTML files.

### Changing the Active Tab

The user is able to change the active tab by clicking the tab link. This is achieved by publishing a `$scope` function in the parent controller:

```
$scope.changeTab = function(tab) {
  $scope.selectedTab.name = tab.name;
}
```

### Creating a Tabs Module

The beauty of AngularJS and its pluggable modular architecture is that you can extend the AngularJS directive ecosystem, and have the directives work together seamlessly.  For example, you could encapsulate the above tabs directive into a `tabs` module, and even use the ngRepeat directive to bind the tabs.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NpT6RIn1O71GUhWcr8qm?p=preview)

#### Controller

```
var app = angular.module('app',['tabs']);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.tabData = [ 
      { name: 'tab1', body: 'You selected tab1!'},
      { name: 'tab2', body: 'You selected tab2!'},
      { name: 'tab3', body: 'You selected tab3!'},
      { name: 'tab4', body: 'You selected tab4!'},
    ];
});
```

#### View

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <tab-container selected="tab1">
     <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabData" name="{{tab.name}}">{{ tab.body }} </tab>
  </tab-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure for controllers/services in Angular are explained well here: 
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

In app.js, we declare an angular application, give it a name, and any dependencies (ng-route / ng-grid). $http calls should be made using a factory or a service, and the controller should call the service to fetch or post data. From the angular documentation, "services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app."
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('appname', []);

app.factory('httpResponseErrorInterceptor'...
app.config(['$httpProvider',...
```

Controller:

```
    angular.module('appname').controller("NameCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", "$window", "$http", "$timeout", "SomeService",
    function ($scope, $log, $window, $http, $timeout, TabService) {

    //your controller code
       $scope.tab = 0;    
       $scope.changeTab = function(newTab){
          $scope.tab = newTab;
       };    
       $scope.isActiveTab = function(tab){
          return $scope.tab === tab;
       }; 
    }
]);
```

Service:

```
angular.module('appname').service("TabService", function () {
   //Your code for shared functionality regarding tab service

   var currentTab = {};

   return {
      currentTab : currentTab 
   }
});
```