# angularjs show/hide tabs, click same tab hide the content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-class

when i click tab A, A content show

when i click tab B, A content hide B content show

but the effect i want is when i click tab A, A content show, click A tab again content hide.

Any suggest will be help thanks

```
<ul class="row text-center">
                <li class="col col-33">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{selected: tab==a}" ng-click="tab = a ">a <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col col-33">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0); "  ng-class="{selected: tab==b}" ng-click="tab = b ">b <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col col-33">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  ng-class="{selected: tab==c}" ng-click="tab = c ">c <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
 <div class="a"  ng-show="tab == a">a</div>
 <div class="b"  ng-show="tab == b">b</div>
 <div class="c"  ng-show="tab == c">c</div>
```

Comment: then your `ng-click` should be `ng-click="tab ? tab =='a' ? null : 'a'"`

Comment: see the example http://plnkr.co/edit/RAeIwFbn2Zoe9WfLdMX8?p=preview

Comment: @XiaoXinqi I've added answer..do looked at it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your expression of `ng-click` to `ng-click="tab = tab=='a'? null: 'a'"`

```
<ul class="row text-center">
    <li class="col col-33">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{selected: tab=='a'}" ng-click="tab = tab=='a'? null: 'a'">
          a <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
          </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col col-33">
        <a href="javascript:void(0); " ng-class="{selected: tab=='b'}" ng-click="tab = tab=='b'? null: 'b' ">
          b 
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="col col-33">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{selected: tab=='c'}" ng-click="tab = tab=='c'? null: 'c' ">
          c <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="a" ng-show="tab == 'a'">a</div>
<div class="b" ng-show="tab == 'b'">b</div>
<div class="c" ng-show="tab == 'c'">c</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have Answered like this [Implementing angularJs factory or service for bootstrap tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553297/implementing-angularjs-factory-or-service-for-bootstrap-tabs/29553411#29553411)

same as I ready the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RAeIwFbn2Zoe9WfLdMX8?p=preview)

```
    <ul>          
    <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"> 
      <a href ng-click="tab = tab==1 ? a : 1">Tab1</a>               
    </li>           
    <li ng-class="{active:tab===2}"> 
       <a href ng-click="tab = tab==2 ? a : 2">Tab2</a>              
    </li>           
    <li ng-class="{active:tab===3}"> 
      <a href ng-click="tab = tab==3 ? a : 3">Tab3</a>           
    </li>           
    <br><br> 
    <p ng-show="tab === 1"> Tab1 content </p>           
    <p ng-show="tab === 2"> Tab2 content</p> 
    <p ng-show="tab === 3"> Tab3 content</p>        
   </ul>
```

here `a` is noting but `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

In would rather modify the ng-click block **null** to **tab**, as on clicking on the same tab nothing should happen!

```
<ul class="row text-center">
      <li class="col col-33">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{selected: tab=='a'}" ng-click="tab = 
           tab=='a'? tab : 'a'">
          a <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
          </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col col-33">
        <a href="javascript:void(0); " ng-class="{selected: tab=='b'}" ng-click="tab = 
    tab=='b'? tab : 'b' ">
          b 
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="col col-33">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{selected: tab=='c'}" ng-click="tab = 
    tab=='c'? tab : 'c' ">
          c <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="a" ng-show="tab == 'a'">a</div>
   <div class="b" ng-show="tab == 'b'">b</div>
   <div class="c" ng-show="tab == 'c'">c</div>
```