# Angularjs - UI Router otherwise and bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

When I'm using Bootstrap tabs, links are automatically redirected to home page as stated in otherwise option. I think it's because of the hash tags in href in tabs.

**Tabs**

```
<ul class="tab-nav" role="tablist" data-tab-color="red" tabindex="7" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none;">
       <li class=""><a href="#home2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#profile2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
        .state ('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
        })

        .state ('home.home-1', {
            url: '/home-1',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })

        .state ('home.home-2', {
            url: '/home-2',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
```

**Main Menu links**

```
<a data-ui-sref-active="active" data-ui-sref="home.home-1">Home 1</a>
<a data-ui-sref-active="active" data-ui-sref="home.home-2">Home 2</a>
```

I'm using pure Bootstrap NOT angular bootstrap module. How can I fix this by preventing extra hash tags? I mean how to prevent redirection when URL changes which are not stated in $stateProvider

Comment: Would be useful to see more ... e.g. **states**. And, maybe I read your issue wrong.. but ... it DOES automatically redirect... and it is good, or not? also would expect that you should have **href="#/home2"** instead of *href="#home2"*

Comment: Hope this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130391/angularjs-show-hide-tabs-click-same-tab-hide-the-content/30130721#30130721

Comment: @RadimKöhler I have updated my question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UitAQiHcFvVfgGqhNiBn?p=preview)

I would say, that we are missing target for children in our parent view

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

This is a must if we use simplified views notation (without **`views : {}`** object). This state definition, is doing two things

1. It inserts the home-1 into parent ui-view
2. It inserts the home-2 into root ui-view, skipping the parent

check updated states:

```
  .state ('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
    })
    .state ('home.home-1', {
        url: '/home-1',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .state ('home.home-2', {
      url: '/home-2',
      views: {
        '@' : {
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        }
      }
    })
```

and parent **`views/common.html`** now contains:

```
<div ui-view>
```

More details from doc:

[View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where **viewname** is the name used in the view directive and **state name** is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.
>
> For example, the previous example could also be written as:

```
.state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters@': { },
      'tabledata@': { },
      'graph@': { }
    }
})
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UitAQiHcFvVfgGqhNiBn?p=preview)

Original part

I would say, that the issue is hidden in this link setting:

```
<a href="#home2"...
```

Because our states are defined:

```
  .state ('home', {
        url: '/home',
        ...
    })
    .state ('home.home-1', {
        url: '/home-1',
        ...
    })
    .state ('home.home-2', {
        url: '/home-2',
        ...
    })
```

And we do not use HTML5 mode, the links must look like this

```
<a href="#/home"...
<a href="#/home/home-1"...
<a href="#/home/home-2"...
```

So:

> any other link (e.g. the original `<a href="#home2"`) is in fact unknown for `UI-Router`. And that's why it is redirect to otherwise setting

Also, any child does inherit url from its parent, the state 'home.home-1' url is built from parent `/home` and its own `/home-1` === `/home/home-1`

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my question wasn't clear enough. I've updated my question again. What I mentioned above in <ul> tags are tab links. I've mentioned main menu links also. Please check.

Comment: @Body, I guess we should have the answer.. I created working plunker, provided some more explanation and tried to give you hints where to check in doc...

Comment: There was a small typo with url placement on home 2, please, check upated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UitAQiHcFvVfgGqhNiBn?p=preview

Comment: @Body, you still do not seem to be happy with that?

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand as I'm new to Angular. If you don't mind could you please implement your method on my plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/Bf7pYsD1sy59nulwnrrF?p=preview. I had setup the plunker actually as I need. As you can see in the plunker, in about page, when clicked a tab it's redirected to home. Can you prevent that by disabling the extra hashes generated by Bootstrap tab or any other way?

Comment: Good you've created broken plunker. There is an example how to fix it: http://plnkr.co/edit/nFVKsl4IQkX7b7UwJTLF?p=preview - mostly I just defined the remaining states (profile, messages)

Comment: Thank you very much, Now I'm getting slowly. I think I'll have to state all the hash changes from tab and collapse in $stateprovider. I'll create a child view for these tabs and collapse. Thanks again for your time.